# I face with This error: site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the main domain which name is example.com . this domain has its own SSL. Recently I decided to run a new website since the reseller do not let me run subdomain.example.com , I start subdomain.example.com on the other hosting. 
But I face this error: 
`This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).`

Both resellers believe their certificate is valid. 
What is the main reason? 
Is it related to the use two different certificates for one domain?